# Creating a position file using ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

I have a HashMap where i store last read time of multiple sources which i needs to be backed up to a file. The same hashmap is updated regularly and should be backed up every time.

I am using ObjectOutputStream for this, as the same object is updated i was doing a `reset()` on the ObjectOutputStream, so that the file is updated, but with this is see and for every `writeObject()` a new line is written to the file this should be because the object is appended to the file. My service is long running service, so i can't afford the object to be appended every time as that will cause the file to become huge.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
public void open() throws WCException {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(bookmarkFile));

        bookmarks = (HashMap<String, Long>) objectInputStream.readObject();

        objectInputStream.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
    }

    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(bookmarkFile);
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new WCException("Bookmarker", e.getCause());
    }
}

public void close() throws WCException {
    try {
        objectOutputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new WCException("Bookmarker", e.getCause());
    }
}

public synchronized void write() throws WCException {
    try {
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(bookmarks);
        objectOutputStream.reset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new WCException("Bookmarker", e.getCause());
    }
}

public synchronized void update(HashMap<String, Long> bookmark) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : bookmark.entrySet()) {
        if (!bookmarks.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
            bookmarks.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        else {
            long last = bookmarks.get(entry.getKey());
            if (last < entry.getValue())
                bookmarks.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

I want something with which there is always a simple object in the file, which is latest. I am even ok with going away from ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: You could re-open the stream every time you write to it - opening a FileOutputStream deletes the previous file contents by default.

Comment: I would be writing probably every 20 seconds or less, so reopening the file every time would be a big overhead.

Comment: What on earth does "with this is see and for every writeObject() a new line is written to the file this should be because the object is appended to the file" mean? Please try again.

Comment: With this i mean, that with every `writeObject()` call the object is appended to the file, instead of updating the object already in the file.